# System.Windows.Input doesn't exist?

Tags: c#

I have `using System.Windows.Input;` at the top of my program, but it gives me an error saying that:

> The type or namespace name 'Input' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

And when I let IntelliSense popup on the period right after `Windows` it only lists `Forms` as a valid option. I'm using .NET framework 4.0 in Visual C# 2010 Express...

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 18):

I suspect you've created a Windows Forms project, instead of a WPF project.

The types contributing to `System.Windows.Input` are in PresentationCore.dll and potentially other WPF-related assemblies.

I don't know enough about the types in `System.Windows.Input` to say for sure whether or not you *can* use them in a Windows Forms app, but I would at least *encourage* you to decide whether to go with Windows Forms or WPF, and then use types *designed* for that UI platform.

Comment: I am using Windows Forms.... do I need to switch to WPF or can I somehow stay with Windows Forms?

Comment: @Jacob: Well what are you trying to use within System.Windows.Input? It may or may not be appropriate for a WinForms app, depending on what you're trying to do. I would *generally* suggest going to WPF as a nicer UI platform, but it depends on your exact requirements.

Comment: You can add both references, but I would stick to one project type, either WPF or Windows Forms and stick with those libraries.

Comment: I'm trying to use GlobalKeyboardHook

Comment: @Jacob: I'm not seeing that type in the documentation... do you have a link anywhere?

Answer (score 10):

For reference, the System.Windows.Input namespace can be accessed by reference to the **WindowsBase assembly**.

Tested using a .Net 4.5 class library (for purposes of mapping System.Windows.Input.Key to prism events).

Answer (score 2):

I added **User Control(WPF)** to the project. This includes necessary references. You can remove it immediately once you compile the program. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL that contains that library and namespace is not currently referenced in your project.

Add a reference to that DLL in your project and then it can be referenced.

The DLL mentioned is part of the WPF framework.  I've included a screenshot of a sample WPF application.  When you created a WPF appliation, you get the presentation framework reference automatically.  Also, note, you can add older Windows Forms references as well if desired.  If you don't create a WPF application, this reference will have to be added manually.

But, I would suggest that you create a WPF application OR Winforms appliation, not a combination of both.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to manage Nuget Package Manager and install
input simulator package and WindowsInput package and the issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Old but not a rare problem for people new to Visual Studio and C#. Perhaps it may be useful to show the solution clearly via screenshots.

From <kbd>Project</kbd> -> <kbd>Add Reference</kbd>:

[image: From Project-> Add Reference]

Add the `PresentationCore`:

[image: Add the PresentationCore]

Answer (score -1):

No need to go through all this, just add the PresentationCore dll into your application. You can do this simply by adding a reference to this DLL.